# CSS How can i remove all styles from one paragraph?

Tags: css, unset

I have a div with a paragraph with many html styles. How can I remove them all from only this one `div/p`?
I done like that:

```
.ex2 em,strong,a,mark,big,small,code,i,abbr,kbd,u {
 all:unset;  
}
```

But maybe there is a better way.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like:

```
#container {
  all: initial;
  * {
    all: unset;
  }
}
```

It should clear all formats for the current container

Comment: is the ex2 class the container for the element that you need to remove all formats?

Comment: Yes, i tried like that:.
.ex2 *{
  all: initial;
  * {
    all: unset;
  } 

    and this is work now :) thank you!
P.S.: Will be the short variant wrong?
 .ex2  * {
    all: unset;
  }